# Configure database connection to run web application anywhere

Tags: php, database, web-applications

Using phpmyadmin as my database software I have created mobile web app that uses php to contact the database. I am using phpmyadmin through the university server. My problem is I don't no how I would go about connecting this database to my web application from anywhere in the world. For example if I’m sending a picture to the database via my web application it doesn't have the right connection to phpmyadmin to work outside of the university environment. Can anybody shed some light on how I would go about this in terms of how to connect to phpmyadmin, does it need different credentials from when I’m using it in the university, and below is an example of how it is currently connecting:

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','USERNAME','PASSWORD') ; 
$db = mysql_select_db('B00556019');
```

Should I be contacting this database differently, like for example changing the localhost to something else? Also can PHP be used to contact the university phpmyadmin database and have my web application working from it? And sorry for the lack of knowledge and detail I'm very much below par with databases. If you need any more details to help understand better let me know. Thank you for your time.

Comment: are you working on the local server on your computer?

Comment: When at university yes, at home I use an FTP client to work with it, but I need it to run anywhere without an FTP

Comment: I think you're just confused about server vs client. phpmyadmin is only a tool to *design* and *manipulate* the database. PHP code and a  mysql db will reside on the server, where mobile clients can connect to them. the PHP <==> mysql connection is "localhost".

Comment: Please ignore my answer. I read mobile app, not mobile web app. Although same still could apply.

Answer (score 0):

Change your connection code as below :

```
 $conn = mysql_connect('Server ip address','username','password') ; 
 $db = mysql_select_db('B00556019');
```

YOu need to change localhost with your server ip.

***Note :***

Most default installs of MySQL only listen to the local machine.

Look for the bind-address setting in my.cnf on the server, and make sure it's listening on the IP address you're targetting. You may also need to ensure skip-networking isn't switched on!

Alternatively (and less securely!) the following will set it up to listen on all addresses - local and remote:

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a webservice and have your mobile app send data to that. Far more secure.

Then the webservice could write them to the database (which could then be on localhost). Webservice will just take queries write them to the database and provide responses over http back to your mobile app.

You also won't get firewall issues as it will all be over HTTP then.